# Why Junit assertThat() passes for two objects depsite the objects being unequal?

Tags: junit, lombok, spring-test

I am comparing two objects `emsResponse` and `expectedEMSResponse` of the same class `EMSResponse` in a Junit test case but the `assertThat(...)` test case passes despite the objects being *unequal*. When I try a normal `equals` on the two objects the output is false but the `assertThat(expectedEMSResponse==eMSResponse)` still passes rather than failing. Please advise.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class RestconfRes {
    
    private String response;
    private int httpStatusCode;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class EMSResponse extends RestconfRes {
    
    private EMSOutput output;
    private EMSErrors errors;
    private String message;
    
    public EMSOutput getOutput() {
        if (output == null) {
            output = new EMSOutput();
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

**// Junit test case**

```
 @Test
        public void processJMSRequestForHappyPathTest() throws Exception {
            // test case logic here
            // mock logic here
EMSResponse emsResponse = processor.processJMSRequest(request);
            System.out.println(" expectedEMSResponse ..." + EMSResponse.toString());
            System.out.println(" processJMSRequestForHappyPathTest expectedEMSResponse  ...:" + expectedEMSResponse.toString());
            System.out.println("check if i am equal..."+ expectedEMSResponse.equals(emsResponse));
            assertThat(expectedEMSResponse==eMSResponse);
        }
```

**Output:**

```
expectedEMSResponse ...EMSResponse(output=EMSoutput(deviceName=null, timestamp=null, status=failure, transId=null, completionStatus=null, serviceId=null, contentProviderName=null, interfaceName=null), errors=EMSerrors(errorType=INTERNAL_FAILURE, errorTag=A41_INTERNAL_EXCEPTION, errorMessage=An internal error occurred within A41. Please contact ASG.), message=null)

emsResponse ...EMSResponse(output=EMSoutput(deviceName=device_3, timestamp=2020-07-15T16:32:31.881000, status=configuring, transId=66427-d8b5-489f-9f8f, completionStatus=in-progress, serviceId=null, contentProviderName=null, interfaceName=null), errors=null, message=null)

check if i am equal...false
```

**Updated second sub question to this**
I changed the call to:

```
assertTrue(expectedEMSResponse==emsResponse);
// gives a java.lang.AssertionError and 
System.out.println("check if i am equal..."+ expectedEMSResponse.equals(emsResponse)); gives output 
check if i am equal...false
```

// this test case passes Ok    assertThat(emsResponse.getOutput().getTransId()).isEqualTo(expectedEMSResponse.getOutput().getTransId());

When I try printing the details of the `emsResponse` and `expecteEMSResponse` classes through `toString()` I get the below output:

```
// gives only a bean as an output
emsResponse.toString():com.myorg.myapp.interfaces.dto.emsResponse#0 bean

//gives the complete object signature
expectedemsResponse.toString():emsResponse(output=emsOutput(deviceName=device_3, 
timestamp=2020-07-15T16:32:31.881000, status=configuring, transId=hello-there-489f-9f8f-abcd, 
completionStatus=in-progress, serviceId=null, contentProviderName=null, interfaceName=null), errors=null, message=null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/) because I don't think JUnit 4 or Hamcrest have a single argument version of `assertThat()`, and JUnit 5 doesn't have such method.

The way AssertJ `assertThat()` works is that the first argument of the call is the actual value that you want to perform assertions on. This returns an assertion object, which provides you a number of assertion methods.

When you call `assertThat(expectedEMSResponse==eMSResponse)`, AssertJ just returns an assertion object for boolean type and nothing else happens.

The correct way to use it would be:

```java
assertThat(eMSResponse).isEqualTo(expectedEMSResponse);
```

Now it returns an assertion object for the first argument, and then performs the `isEqualTo()` assertion on that one. The `assertThat()` call only works as an entry point to different assertions that can be performed on the first argument.

Comment: That's right. I didn't notice that. I have changed the call  to assertTrue(expectedEMSResponse==emsResponse); and  end up with a java.lang.AssertionError. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: If I do  assertThat(emsResponse.getOutput().getTransId()).isEqualTo(expectedEMSResponse.getOutput().getTransId()); this works fine and passes the test case

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are using assertThat correctly. Looks like you need to pass additional arguments as well. These are the method definitions:

```
assertThat(T actual, Matcher<? super T> matcher)

assertThat(String reason, T actual, Matcher<? super T> matcher)
```

Also as per the documentation, it is deprecated. Might I suggest that you use assertEquals() instead?

The documentation: https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat

Answer (score 1):

This does not fail because you are not using junit correctly:

```
        @Test
        public void processJMSRequestForHappyPathTest() throws Exception {
            // test case logic here
            // mock logic here
EMSResponse emsResponse = processor.processJMSRequest(request);
            System.out.println(" expectedEMSResponse ..." + EMSResponse.toString());
            System.out.println(" processJMSRequestForHappyPathTest expectedEMSResponse  ...:" + expectedEMSResponse.toString());
            System.out.println("check if i am equal..."+ expectedEMSResponse.equals(emsResponse));
            assertThat(expectedEMSResponse==eMSResponse);
        }
```

You should have:

```
            assertTrue(expectedEMSResponse==eMSResponse);
            assertEquals(expectedEMSResponse, eMSResponse);
```

Or using `assertThat` with [assertj](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/):

```
assertThat(eMSResponse).isEqualTo(expectedEMSResponse);
```

This should help you understand:

- junit 5: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/
- junit 4: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-assertions

Comment: Thank you ! I changed to assertTrue(expectedEMSResponse==emsResponse);  and now am getting a java.lang.AssertionError. any idea why?

Comment: ... probably because the expression `expectedEMSResponse==emsResponse` is not true.